# Make complex shape without modeling

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects, effects

I want to make an object like this:

[image: object]

[image: object 2]
But it is way too hard for me to model. It dosen't have to be the exact same, just the same look.
Is there a trick to modeling it, or some kind of generated texture?

Comment: For this kind of modelling (which I assume the worklfow is - subdivide, decimate, wireframe, etc. modifiers) there is a neat (free) add-on called [By-Gen](https://gumroad.com/l/BY-GEN) by [Curtis Holt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Y8Zl1RWya4). You can try some examples and study the modifier order to get this kind of results

Answer (score 1):

One "trick" you could try to use is adding texture with transparent "holes" to basic geometries, overlapping them to replicate some similar pattern. The "import images as planes" add-on (included but disabled by default) could ease the process somehow.

Eg:

[image]

Comment: That's an interesting idea, but I don't think it would work for the tower parts. I'll certainly try it with the ground though!